# Insert multiple text inputs with same name, into one cell in MySql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have multiple inputs

```
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" >
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" >
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" >
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" >
...and so on (depending on how many they want)
```

On form submit (using $_POST), i want to take all of the inputs (which by the way, we'll never now how many will be there [dynamic jquery add/remove input form] ) and combine them into one variable, all nicely separated by ^^^.

B.T.W, I am using this format to insert into mysql

```
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mixtapes (title, songs, posted_by_id, description, date) 
     VALUES('$mixtapetitle','$allmixtapetracks','$posted_by_id','$mixtapedescription', now())")  
     or die (mysql_error());
```

---

So in the end i want to pack all of the dynamic inputs into one single variable, each one separated by ^^^. The example below is how i want the variable $allmixtapetracks to look, so when I insert it, it looks EXACTLY like that.

**Value of input 1^^^Value Of Input 2^^^Value of Input 3^^^Value of input 4^^^**

---

## EDIT:

This coding is causing my error. When the inputs are dynamicly created, the php $_POST ignores them. Why? I am not sure.

### JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 3;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>40){
            alert("The maximum allowed tracks is 40");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.html('<table><tr><td width="88"><label>Track #'+ counter + ' : </label></td><td><input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" ></td></tr></table>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup").hide().show(50);


    counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==3){
          alert("Your mixtape must contain at least two tracks!");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove().show().hide(40);

     });


  });
</script>
```

### HTML:

```
 <form action="add-mixtape.php" name="addmixtapeForm" class="addmixtapeForm" id="addmixtapeForm" autocomplete="off" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
             <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
             <table>
              <tr>
               <td width="88"><label>Track #1: </label></td>
               <td><input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" ></td>
              </tr>
             </table>
             <table>
              <tr>
               <td width="88"><label>Track #2: </label></td>
               <td><input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" ></td>
              </tr>
             </table>
             </div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Add Track" id="addButton" class="addREMOVEmixtapetrack">
            <input type="button" value="Remove Track" id="removeButton" class="addREMOVEmixtapetrack">
</form>
```

Comment: Note that this breaks even the first normal form of database structures. You should avoid storing multiple values in the same field since it's very hard to query the data that way (but who needs to search on track names anyway, right?). Even more problematic is that you have no question! What do you need and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$alltracks = implode('^^^', $_POST['track']) . '^^^';
```

Test code:

```
<?php
$alltracks = implode('^^^', $_POST['track']) . '^^^';
echo $alltracks;
?>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" >
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" >
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" >
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="text" id="track[]" name="track[]" >
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I've tried this one, and it only gives the value of the first input

Comment: Then the tracks aren't being posted correctly.  Can you show a var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: Just tested myself.


plugged some stuff in and it printed: this ^^^is ^^^a^^^test^^^

Comment: this worked brilliantly on testing! this shows that your code works like a charm, it's just for some reason it's only inserting the first inputs value when it goes into my mysql row.

Comment: Make sure you are escaping your string properly with mysql_real_escape_string, it may be an accidental ' screwing things up.  Also try echoing your query to make sure the data gets there correctly

Comment: I figured out my problem. I am using a script that dynamically adds and removes the inputs if less/more is needed. When i was (by default) starting off with one input, the only one being inserted was the one that was on pageload. And the rest that were dynamicly created, were ignored. I wanted to see if that's what was causing the problem, so i added another default input and there was two tracks and the rest were ignored. This means there is something wrong with my javascript/jquery coding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9839/discussion-between-andrew-leap-and-alex-sarnowski)

Answer (score 2):

I *strongly* recommend against storing multiple values in one column. The correct strategy is to create a normalized table which links mixtapes to tracks:

```
CREATE TABLE tapetracks (
  mixtapeid INT NOT NULL,
  trackname VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
```

Then loop over the input values and insert each into the table:

```
$mixtapeid = <the current tape you are adding to>;
foreach ($_POST['track'] AS $track) {
  $track = mysql_real_escape_string($track);
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tapetracks (mixtapeid, trackname) VALUES ($mixtapeid, '$track')");
  if (!$result) {
    echo mysql_error();
    break;
  }
}
```

When storing multiple values in one column, you lose the ability to utilize a column index when querying, and it becomes a big hassle to query for individual values, requiring calls to `REPLACE()` and `FIND_IN_SET()` which may fail if the track names contain commas.  It really is the wrong strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure you can:

```
$combined = "";
foreach ( $_POST['track'] as $t ){
    $combined .= $t . "^^^";
}
$combined = substr(0,-3, combined) // only if you want to strip last 3 "^^^" symbols
```

This should do it....

Comment: As @Andrew Leap suggested, please update your answer with `$_POST` `vardump` but it would also be good to show up you actual code. That way we should be able to pinpoint the problem...